# linux openGL depth_test not working

Tags: opengl, depth-testing

I tried a lot of methods on the Internet but it still not working.
now i think about if the trouble is related to my OS (ubuntu).

```
void init(void){
glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glClearDepth(1.0);
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
init2();
}

void reshape(int w, int h){
int t = min (w,h);
glViewport (0, 0,  t, t);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(-100.0, 100.0, -100.0, 100.0, 1.1, 200.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(40.0, 40.0, 100.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
}
```

Two functions above are from my code..

Comment: Do you actually request a depth buffer when creating the gl _window_?

Answer (score 0):

`glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)` must be called at the beginning of every frame to clear both the color buffer and the depth buffer.

Other than that, you should post more details. What are you seeing? How are you requesting the OpenGL context? Could you post the whole draw loop?